# JSTL: Absolute value of a BigDecimal (Proper way...)

Tags: java, jstl, bigdecimal, absolute

Pardon me for the brain fart tonight but for some reason... this is the best solution I can come up with right now on getting the ABS of a `BigDecimal` with JSTL right now... No math tricks outside of ABS too.  I have to maintain precision.

I know there is a better way to handle it... what's your suggestion?  Any google search is pulling up help on `formatNumber` and handling currencies for the delta/negatives.

```
<c:forEach items="${arr}" var="cursor" varStatus="itemsRow">
  <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${cursor.value < 0}">
      <td width="75px" align="right">
        <fmt_rt:formatNumber pattern="#,###,###,###.##" value="${cursor.value * -1}" minFractionDigits="2"/></td>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
      <td width="75px" align="right">
        <fmt_rt:formatNumber pattern="#,###,###,###.##" value="${cursor.value}" minFractionDigits="2"/></td>
    </c:otherwise>
  </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: your sample looks like HTML with some PHP parsed in.

Comment: @Jon Which part looks like PHP? Looks like JSP to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use BigDecimal.abs() on the server side; don't do this kind of work in the JSP.

If you *must*, wrap it up in a JSP-based custom tag, or create a JSTL function wrapper to handle the abs.

Also, refactor, similar to this (completely untested), if you can't do the work in an appropriate place:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:forEach items="${arr}" var="cursor" varStatus="itemsRow">
  <c:set name="val" value="${cursor.value < 0 ? cursor.value * -1 : cursor.value}"/>
  <td width="75px" align="right">
    <fmt_rt:formatNumber pattern="#,###,###,###.##" value="${val}" minFractionDigits="2"/>
  </td>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: The problem is that these objects are generated so I shouldn't be touching any of the encapsulation methods on the server side.  It is a great suggestion though, with some of the display changes formatting I'm going to have to make.  It might be easier to go ahead and define some of my own tags.

Comment: The ternary set you provided is perfect for now.  I was a bit delirious last night. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Vehemon What objects are generated? There's nothing between the item object and the JSP?

Comment: I simplified my example.  arr is actually part of a complex structure of hibernate mappings.  The objects I'm working with are stubs from middlegen or some other tool they are using for stub/dao generation.  I try to stay out of their hibernate packages because those guys have a quick fuse. ;)  I don't want to tilt them before Christmas.  I'll save that for 2012.

Comment: @Vehemon That code wouldn't live on that layer, it would live it the servlet, controller, etc. used as the bridge between the data and external web/service interface.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using some sort of MVC framework, or at least have a servlet feeding the data to your JSP, I'd suggest building your list of BigDecimals in the controller / servlet as absolute values - use BigDecimal.abs() - so that you don't have to muck up the JSP with this kind of stuff.